# Taking the two extremities of a vector port without editing the assignements

Tags: vhdl

My development board offers ten switches, which I can access via the port `SW : in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)`. I'd like to be able to only have SW(9) and SW(0) declared to get rid of warnings in my compiler. Is this possible without editing the pin assignments for my board ?

---

In my ports :

```
SW : in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
```

In my architecture :

```
alias lSW is SW(9);
alias rSW is SW(0);
```

I'd like (8 downto 1) to not be defined.

Comment: Why cant you just change the port names in the top level file and change the pin assignments in the project?

Comment: Show the entire warnings. They'll identify the tool and reason(s). Warnings are tool implementation dependent in VHDL.

Comment: @Tricky I simply don't want to. I could but I want one assignement for all my projects.

Comment: @user1155120 Quartus Prime Lite 18.1; The warnings are just this, warnings. They don't do anything. I'm just asking the question to know if it is possible.

Comment: Simple answer: No, not possible. A range is a range and has no undefined intermediate positions.

Comment: Feel free to answer then